# Find and remove pattern of a string (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

I have a big string ... Original text something like that:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  <a href="hxxp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_1">hxxp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_1</a>
Sed lacinia purus turpis. Curabitur in nisi urna, vitae aliquet
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus hxxp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_2</a>'
```

If you notice there is a video (VIDEO_2) that has a closing < /a> without opening < a>
Those problematic videos can be anywhere and any number inside the original text.

I want to remove those unnecessary < /a>
How can I detect and delete those?

I am on Delphi XE4.
Any help please?

Comment: What is a video 'that has a closing without opening'?

Comment: I edited the question, now its more clear.

Comment: Do you want to do this in source code editor or at runtime ?

Comment: Of course in runtime, that is why I posted "Delphi"

Comment: Either use an html parser that will forgive such nonsense, or fix the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following code works efficiently:

```
function RemoveLonelyClosingATags(const S: string): string;
var
  level: integer;
  i: Integer;
  ActualLength: integer;
begin
  level := 0;
  SetLength(result, Length(S));
  ActualLength := 0;
  i := 1;
  while i <= Length(S) do
  begin
    if (S[i] = '<') and (UpperCase(Copy(S, i, 4)) = '</A>') then
    begin
      if Level = 0 then
      begin
        inc(i, 4);
        Continue;
      end
      else
        dec(Level);
    end;

    inc(ActualLength);
    result[ActualLength] := S[i];
    if (S[i] = '<') and (i < Length(S)) and (UpperCase(S[i+1]) = 'A') then
    begin
      inc(Level);
      if Level > 1 then
        raise Exception.Create('Nested A tags detected.');
    end;
    inc(i);

  end;
  SetLength(result, ActualLength);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A general function:

```
Function TagStripper(inString: String; beginTag : String; endTag: String): String;
Var
  index : Integer;
  startTag : Integer;
  closeTag : Integer;
Begin
  index := 1;
  While (index > 0) Do
    Begin
      closeTag := PosEx(endTag, inString, index);
      startTag := PosEx(beginTag, inString, index);
      If startTag = 0 Then
        startTag := closeTag;
      index := closeTag;
      If (closeTag <= startTag) And (index > 0) Then
        Delete(instring, closeTag, Length(endTag))
      Else
        If closeTag > 0 Then
          index := index + Length(endTag);
    End;
  Result := inString;
End;
```

Essentially it looks for an opening and closing tag. If the closing tag comes before the opening one it deletes it. The beginning point to search (index) is then rebased from wherever it found the closing tag. beginTag and endTag in your example would be

```
'<a' and '</a>'.
```

The result when running it is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  <a
 href="hxxp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_1">hxxp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_1</a>
 Sed lacinia purus turpis. Curabitur in nisi urna, vitae aliquet
 Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
 hxxp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_2
```

Comment: Good, but of course the `Delete` is non-optimal in terms of performance. (That's why I use the `ActualLength` pattern.)

Comment: Oh there's lots of debate between myself and others on Embarcadero's forum about this subject :-). Let's just say I believe the focus should be on readability first and optimization only take place if performance is observed to be unacceptable. That said, I had no problem understanding how your method worked.